# Генерация html страниц по шаблону

Tags: html, веб-программирование

Я новичок в программировании, особенно веб, мне нужно генерировать простые статические страницы используя шаблон. Какие есть легкие и понятные решения, чтобы можно было поставить на хостинг 000webhost и через вебстраницу генерировать страницы по шаблону, вводя нужные данные

---

Нужно именно чтобы было все автоматически, ввел что нужно отобразить на странице, и она по шаблону создалась

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Берите любой язык, который поддерживается хостингом (похоже, пхп там работает) и делайте себе код. Хотя можно и на локальной машине генерить, а потом заливать